# How to start new activity in same tab?

Tags: android, listview, tabactivity

I have 2 tabs, named : Tab1, Tab2
class MainActivity extends TabActivity.
**MainActivity.java**

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mTabHost = getTabHost();
    Intent intentTab;
    intentTab = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab1Activity.class);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_1").setIndicator("Tab1")
            .setContent(intentTab));

    intentTab = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab2Activity.class);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_2").setIndicator("Tab2")
            .setContent(intentTab));



    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

**main.xml**

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dp" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
        android:layout_weight="0" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Tab1Activity extends ListActvity** which parse json and list the result in listview.
On clicking item in listview, i want to start new acitivity in same tab i.e in Tab-1.
How can i do that ??
**Tab1Activity.java**

```
    public class Tab1Activity extends ListActivity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab1);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,     String>>();

    // Creating JSON Parser instance
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // getting JSON string from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

    try {
        // Getting Array of Root
        root = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ROOT);

        // looping through All root
        for (int i = 0; i < root.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = root.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable

            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
            String town = c.getString(TAG_TOWN);
            String totalRating = c.getString(TAG_TOTALRATING);

            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

            map.put(TAG_NAME, "Name: " + name);
            map.put(TAG_TOWN, "Town: " + town);
            map.put(TAG_RATING, "Rating: " + totalRating);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            myList.add(map);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    /**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, myList,
            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_TOWN,
                    TAG_RATING }, new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.address,
                    R.id.rating });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            //what code should i write to start new activity in this tab i.e Tab1
        }

    });

}
```

}

Here in above code:

```
    // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            //what code should i write to start new activity in this tab i.e Tab1
        }

    });
```

**What code should i write in this ItemClickListener to start new activity in this tab i.e Tab-1 ???**

**tab1.xml**

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/background"
  android:orientation="vertical" >


  <ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

**list_item.xml**

```
  <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:textColor="#43bd00"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/town"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:textColor="#acacac" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rating"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:textColor="#acacac" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanx !!!

Comment: I really am not sure. But I think that using `Intent` with `startActivity()` in the `OnItemClick` Listener of your listview would start the activity in the same tab as the current tab is Tab-1 itself. And dont forget to `finish()` the activity once you are done. Sorry for this "not being sure" but until you get an answer,why don't you try it? BTW, good question. +1

Comment: I wrote this code :  
`Intent testIntent=new Intent(view.getContext(), NextActivity.class);
    startActivity(testIntent);
    finish();`  
New activity starts but the problem is that tab dissapears ??

Comment: Since that's not working out.Just extend the new activity to TabActivity and include those tabs again in this new activity for the time being. I am gonna try this since its kinda interesting and will let you know if I get any success. \m/

Comment: Thanx @Exorcist for the reply, i solve my problem from following link:  
[Experience - Multiple Android Activities in a TabActivity](http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your activity which is to be used as content of tabs, fragments. Fragment may have their own back stack.

See Link:

http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-tabs-with-fragments/